# Suddenly error "An existing connection was forcibly closed" occurs on SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

We have an asp.net solution placed on an old Windows 2012 server. The SQL Server is on a new Windows 2019 server. It has worked for 6 months, but today we suddenly got an error

> An existing connection was forcibly closed

when running the website.

I looked into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/tls-exist-connection-closed but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/965564/how-to-solve-34an-existing-connection-was-forcibly.html?

Comment: Yes I have testet that without success

Comment: There are several reasons that message could appear, some not even related to TLS. Do you have any more of the exception message for context? Especially a stack trace?

Comment: does your certificates not ended ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/apps-forcibly-closed-tls-connection-errors

I used IISCrypto to disable the weak ciphers